# Formik resetting form to initial values

Tags: reactjs, formik, formik-material-ui

I am using Formik and have the following setup below where I want to be able to reset the form when the user presses the "Cancel" button. On return to the form, all form values should be reset to `initialValues` which are all nulls.

```
        <Formik
          enableReinitialize
          initialValues={{ 
            ...INITIAL_FORM_STATE
          }}
          validationSchema={ FORM_VALIDATION }
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
          {({ values, errors, isSubmitting, isValid, setFieldValue, handleChange, resetForm }) => (

          <Form>
             .....
```

I have the following code for the **Cancel** button:

```
                  <Button
                      text="Cancel"
                      startIcon={<UndoIcon />}
                      variant="contained"
                      color="default"
                      className={classes.buttons}                          
                      component={Link} 
                      to={'/home'}
                      onClick={() => { 
                          {resetForm}
                          setMenu("Home")
                      }}
                  />
```

After entering some text into a form field and pressing the Cancel button, which directs me back to the Home page, I then go back to the form and notice that my text is still in state within the form and not resetting.

Can anyone please assist with what I am missing.

Comment: Make sure you have value attribute written in each element.

Answer (score 6):

```
              <Button
                  text="Cancel"
                  startIcon={<UndoIcon />}
                  variant="contained"
                  color="default"
                  className={classes.buttons}                          
                  component={Link} 
                  to={'/home'}
                  onClick={() => { 
                      resetForm()
                      setMenu("Home")
                  }}
              />
```

You should use the `resetForm()` as a function call

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately this didn't solve my issue. Still not resetting.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to set values of the input boxes to formik values:

```
<Formik
          enableReinitialize
          initialValues={{ 
            ...INITIAL_FORM_STATE
          }}
          validationSchema={ FORM_VALIDATION }
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
          {({ values, errors, isSubmitting, isValid, setFieldValue, handleChange, resetForm }) => (
<input value={values.propertyName}/>
          <Form>
```

and now resetForm should work well

Answer (score 1):

`

```
const myForm = useFormik({
    initialValues:{ 
    value1:'',
    value2:''
    },
    onSubmit:( values ) = >{
     //submit data 
     ........

     //reset form after submit
     myForm.resetForm()
    }
)
```

on return

```
 <form onSubmit={myForm.submit}>
     ........
     <Button type="submit"/>
     <Button onClick={()=>myForm.resetForm()}>Reset</Button>
    </form>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You must change values through `values` since you dont have access to `resetForm` from the button.

```
<Button
text="Cancel"
startIcon={<UndoIcon />}
variant="contained"
color="default"
className={classes.buttons}                          
component={Link} 
to={'/home'}
onClick={() => { 
    values = {
     someProperty: null,
    }
}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As as I see your are using [Material UI](https://mui.com/material-ui/). I notice that you have a "to" property in your Button component I think you have to decide either remaining on the same page and reset your form or redirecting to another page. If you want to remain on the same page I would suggest you to get rid of it because this causes some conflict. You can implement it like this:

```
  return (<Formik
  enableReinitialize
  initialValues={{ 
    ...INITIAL_FORM_STATE
  }}
  validationSchema={ FORM_VALIDATION }
  onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
       actions.setSubmitting(false);
       console.log("Submit form", values);
   }}
>
  {({ values, errors, isSubmitting, isValid, setFieldValue, handleChange, handleSubmit, resetForm }) => (

  <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  ..... some inputs
  <Button
                  text="Cancel"
                  startIcon={<UndoIcon />}
                  variant="contained"
                  color="default"
                  className={classes.buttons}
                  component={Link}                          
                  onClick={() => handleReset(resetForm)}
              />
  </Form>
   )}
  </Formik>
  );
```

And inside you class create a handleReset method:

```
  const handleReset = (resetForm) => {
    if (window.confirm('Reset?')) {
      resetForm();
      setMenu("Home");
    }
  };
```